# Receiving warnings trying to create a Video Progress Bar

Tags: react-native, expo

I am receiving these two warnings:

> WARN  [MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak
> detected. 11 getCurrentTime listeners added. Use
> emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit]  WARN
> [MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak
> detected. 11 getDuration listeners added. Use
> emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit]

that displayed in my browser hundreds of times, nonstop, whenever I would go to the specific page where I have my progress bar and video.

This is my current code snippet:

```
const updateProgress = useCallback(() => {
    playerRef.current?.getCurrentTime().then(currentTime => {
      playerRef.current?.getDuration().then(duration => {
        const normalizedTime = currentTime / duration;
        setCurrentProgress(normalizedTime);
      });
    });
  
    requestAnimationFrame(updateProgress);
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // Use a variable to track whether the component is mounted
    let isMounted = true;
  
    const update = () => {
      if (isMounted) {
        updateProgress();
        // Continue the animation frame loop
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
      }
    };
  
    update(); // Start the animation frame loop
  
    return () => {
      // Set isMounted to false when the component unmounts
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

I'm expecting this to update the progress bar to match the current video time.

Comment: Which video library are you using? I'd think that there would be an event like [react-native-video's](https://react-native-video.github.io/react-native-video/component/events#onprogress) `onProgress` that wont require you to use `requestAnimationFrame`